# Moving Structures into a Cell Array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How do I write a cell array where cell(1,1) is an 18 by 1 matrix where every element is a structure with the properties FirstName, LastName, Program, and Section? Here is the structure I have with 18 entries:

studentStruct()

ans =

18x1 struct array with fields:

```
FirstName
LastName
Program
Section
Midterm
Final
Quiz1
Quiz2
Quiz3
Quiz4
Quiz5
```

If I choose to access studentStruct(1,1) this is what I get:

ans =

```
FirstName: 'Tom'
 LastName: 'Jones'
  Program: 'Evening MBA'
  Section: 81
  Midterm: 63
    Final: 59
    Quiz1: 69
    Quiz2: 85
    Quiz3: 90
    Quiz4: 100
    Quiz5: 56
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STRUCT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct2cell.html) function:

```
studentCell = struct2cell(studentStruct)';
```

To have first 4 structure fields in separate cells:

```
studentCell = mat2cell(studentCell(:,1:4), numel(y), ones(1,4))
```

A numeric field (like Section) you can convert to numeric matrix in the cell array:

```
studentCell{4} = cell2mat(studentCell{4});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you could use:

```
cellval = {studentStruct()};
```

Comment: With the current wording of the OP's question, this is the correct answer.